# Python script won't open Youtube stream in vlc

Tags: python, youtube, pafy

I'm trying to open a youtube stream in vlc 3.0.11.1 (macOS mojave 10.14.6)
When I run the script, a python window starts but nothing happens after that
In the terminal :
[00007fa7eff66ae0] videotoolbox decoder: Using Video Toolbox to decode 'h264'
[00007fa7eff66ae0] videotoolbox decoder: vt cvpx chroma: 420v

Here's my code :

```
import pafy
import vlc
import sys

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hTWKbfoikeg"

video = pafy.new(url)
best = video.getbest()
i = vlc.Instance()
media = vlc.MediaPlayer(best.url)
if sys.platform == "darwin":
    from PyQt6 import QtCore
    from PyQt6 import QtGui
    from PyQt6 import QtWidgets

    vlcApp =QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    vlcWidget = QtWidgets.QFrame()
    vlcWidget.resize(700, 700)
    vlcWidget.show()
    media.set_nsobject(int(vlcWidget.winId()))
media.play()

while True:
     pass
```

Comment: You need to call `vlcApp.exec_()` to start the Qt message loop.  Do that instead of the infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks so much @TimRoberts !